How i can compile iperf3 as a lib.so to use that as a library on an android application? (android 9+)
I need to run iperf3 to make measurements "openSource" for a university project but I've only been able to compile iperf as a binary and use it through adb as indicated in this repo https://github.com/davidBar-On/android-iperf3. Could someone explain to me how I can compile it as a lib.so?
My objetive is to compile a version of iperf in shared library format instead of a standalone executable because if I have iperf as a .so library, I could integrate iperf's functionality directly into a mobile application.
Thanks :D.

Please don't spam useless tags.

Looking at the Makefile, the iperf codebase is actually split into a static library (libiperf.la) and the command iperf3 is a single main.c file that links to it.
Build the static library yourself and then link it to your Android library. All of this is covered in the Android NDK documentation.
